# when the array x[] length is more than 1 the logic doesnt work, but the array y[] can be any length

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, iterator, iteration

x[] is first semester, y[] is second semester. everything works well when only one course is registered in x[], but when 2 courses are registered, the if else is messed up.
when x[]'length is more than one,the logic doesnt work, but this array y[] can be any length, it doesnt affect the logic.

```
public static void PreRequist(int x[],int y[]){
    for (int i=0;i<y.length;i++){
        if(y[i]==4){
            for(int j=0;j<x.length;j++){
                if(x[j]!=1){
                toString(courseName(4),courseName(1));
                }
            }
        }}}
```

Comment: How does the logic not work. Its a lot of code to look at and try to decipher. Btw, if you format your code better it becomes a lot better to follow. The curly braces are not all aligned.

Comment: i think the problem is here  '' if (x[j] != 1) '', as i said when the length of x[] is 1, everything works fine, but when it more than one, the toString is called regardless.

Comment: What values are being passed into x and y and why shouldn't the toString be called in that conditional? It isn't clear just from looking at your code what it is supposed to be doing.

Comment: 2 arrays are being passed, each number in the array represents a course. so for example: y[] can have number 4 until x[] has number 1. if its just one number in x[] its fine, but when x[] has 1,2,3 in it, then it enters conditional statement every time.

Comment: I still don't have that good of an idea of what you're doing. Perhaps what you want, while still keeping most of the code the same, is to set a boolean variable initially to false. In the conditional set it to true. After the loop- check to see the value. If false- print. If true- continue further.

Comment: this idea suddenly came to me before seeing your comment, thanks..

Comment: public static boolean checkCourse(int []x,int num){
    boolean available=false;
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
                    if (x[j] == num) {
                        available=true;
                    }
                     
                    }
        return available;
    }

Comment: i made a method for it since the codes were duplicated

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand but I think you could change the conditional "`!=`" to "`==`" for each Ifs `x[j]!=1`, `x[j]!=2`, `x[j]!=3`, `x[j]!=4`...

So each semester will represent their courses. It's what I was able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

i had to remove the second loop and the second array and place them into a method separately. That did the trick!

```
 public static boolean checkCourse(int []x,int num){

boolean available=false;
    for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
                if (x[j] == num) {
                    available=true;
                }

                }
    return available;
}
```